# Any suggestions for a password manager app?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, password

I currently have MiniKeePass on my iPhone and although it does the basic job of storing passwords, I don't have the ability to create random passwords from the app itself and sync the changes to Dropbox.

I'm looking for a subscription-free iOS app that had a clean, modern and beautifully designed UI.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you're using a current version of MiniKeePass? I can both generate passwords and save the database back to Dropbox on my iPhone. The wrench icon next to the password field when making a new entry brings up the generator and the share button at the bottom of the database screen lets you send it to DropBox. It won't sync it automatically, you actually have to hit that button, but you only need to do it when you change the database.

Comment: Wow I actually didn't know that. Yeah I'm running the latest version. I guess that solves all my concerns with MiniKeePass. I never noticed the share button down at the bottom of the screen (mainly because I wasn't expecting it there since you won't normally 'share' the stuff in the app). Thanks for your input!

Comment: 1Password is free at AppStore at the moment with the release of iOS 8.

Answer (score 21):

I use [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) which is available for macOS ([AppStore](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/1password-7/id1333542190?mt=12) or [directly from AgileBits](https://1password.com/downloads/)), [iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/1password/id568903335?mt=8), [Windows](https://1password.com/downloads/) and [Android](https://1password.com/downloads/) and offers both requirements you've listed (random passwords and Dropbox syncing).

Answer (score 5):

[KeePass](http://keepass.info/) is a free, open source, and cross platform password manager, which has the benefit that your password file can be used on multiple devices (Linux, Windows, OSX, iOS and Android). I usually use DropBox to sync the password database between my devices.

Unfortunately the official binary on OSX required an X Server, which made it awkward to use compared to it's competitors.

Fortunately there is [MacPass](http://mstarke.github.io/MacPass/), which is a native port of KeePass for OSX. While it's not as well known as 1Password, it is however free and open source, meaning that you can (potentially) check it's source code, if you don't believe it's secure enough, or contains hidden backdoors.

Also since it's a KeePass port, it can open and edit your MiniKeePass files as well.

Comment: [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) is the better replacement for KeePass and KeePassX. Highly recommended. [Here's a guide](https://sts10.github.io/2017/06/27/keepassxc-setup-guide.html) for getting it setup.

Comment: @QuinnComendant they are both actively updated. KeePassXC is better if you wish to have one app that works cross-platform, MacPass however looks much-much more native on OSX. Feature wise they look very similar.

Comment: KeePass is active, and fine if you're on Windows. KeePassX has had no updates since Sep 2016, and has 80 pending pull requests (including one titled [KeepassX no longer maintained](https://github.com/keepassx/keepassx/pull/204)).

Comment: @QuinnComendant I didn't mention KeePassX at all in my answer

Comment: Oh, you meant KeePass and KeePassXC "are both actively updated"? Sorry, it wasn't clear.

Comment: I mean that KeePassXC, the one you mentioned and MacPass, the one in my post are both actively maintained and have similar feature sets, so I'd say it's more of a personal preference which one you'd use on OSX (KeePassXC being more cross-platform, MacPass being more native looking)

Answer (score 2):

OS X and iOS come with Keychain built-in. The passwords are automatically synced between your Mac and iOS device. You can access the passwords on both.

I've used a number of the password managers mentioned in the comments, even the insanely overpriced [1Password](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/1password/id568903335?mt=8), and, though some may have slightly slicker UIs than Keychain, nothing compares on iOS with Keychain's auto-fill. The closest match on iOS would be iCab browser's password fill and services option, but to get full functionality you'd have to also be using iCab browser on OS X and the desktop version simply isn't up to snuff.

Comment: I liked the idea of Keychain and the ecosystem-wide and iCloud integration... but since I use Chrome on iPhone and OS X, I couldn't get the password auto-fill to work outside of Safari on iPhone and Mac. That was kind of deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 1):

### [Locko](http://www.binarynights.com/locko/) by BinaryNights

- Mac app is on sale for $0.99
- iOS app is expected to be released soon
- Clean, OS X Yosemite influenced design
- Dropbox sync

Description from the Mac App Store:

> Locko is a beautiful and easy-to-use password manager and file vault. You can store confidential information such as web logins, credit card data, computer accounts, software licenses, private pictures and documents, and much more. Locko supports iCloud and Dropbox so you can keep your data synchronized across multiple computers while maintaining absolute security.
>
> • Secure AES-256 encryption
> • Configurable password generator
> • Web Logins, Credit Cards, Bank Accounts, Software Licenses, and so much more…
> • File vault
> • Photo album
> • Secure Notes
> • Custom fields (text, password, date, secure text)
> • Search in all fields
> • Unlimited item groups
> • Browser extensions for Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera
> • 1 click login for websites
> • QuickLook encrypted documents
> • iCloud and Dropbox synchronisation
> • Import from 1Password
> • Export database in JSON format

Comment: It's indeed beautiful but I don't recommend trusting proprietary software for sensitive stuff such as passwords.

Comment: It's actually pretty nice!

Answer (score 0):

Use [KeePass](http://keepass.info). Does the job for me.

> KeePass is a free open source password manager, which helps you to manage your passwords in a secure way. You can put all your passwords in one database, which is locked with one master key or a key file. So you only have to remember one single master password or select the key file to unlock the whole database. The databases are encrypted using the best and most secure encryption algorithms currently known (AES and Twofish).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) is the better replacement for KeePass and KeePassX. Highly recommended. [Here's a guide](https://sts10.github.io/2017/06/27/keepassxc-setup-guide.html) for getting it setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use text/edit app tool(you can find Text/Edit app in launch pad under other section) and type in for example "Stack Exchange Account Information:", then hit enter, and below that you can type "email address:", then type name of it, hit enter then type "Password:", then go to your web browser and you can go to https://randompasswordgen.com , then be sure to include symbols in your password and be sure your password is strong. strong passwords are long up to 128 by example, a password containing 2048 characters long is what can be called unbelievable passwords, but that can be saved in text edit document, but you may wanna create new folder to put you document into. and you may want a usb flash drive to store the folder container containing the account information which would include your password. so what you can do is, in https://randompasswordgen.com, in my opinion and recommendation go for 50 characters long, check mark symbols, hit the generate password button, then highlight the generated long password, right click, hit copy, then paste the generated password into your textedit document below " Password:" text then give name title of document and you can call it "Stack Exchange Ask Different Account Information", y default you'll probably see rtf at end of your title name of document. after that be sure to go down pointed arrow to select location to save the document into, you can if you like select downloads then you can go to file and hit save, then go to downloads tab and you'll find the document you saved. you can drag and drop the document into the new folder on your desktop then drag the folder into usb storage. I named my external usb storage "VAULT" but you can name yours whatever you like. I hope you found this helpful. edits of this answer is fine with me.

Comment: and by the way you can use this method with text edit every time you create an online account. please be sure to not delete your document containing your account information. you can make an extra copy of it for safety reasons if needed.